# How to add the variables in MIB files in the linux?

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, snmpd

Basically, I have added one variable called "sysFirst" (as shown in the below picture)in the available "RFC1213-MIB.txt" file. After addition of the variable I have validated also using command

```
smilint -l 6 -i namelength-32 ./RFC1213-MIB.txt
```

So I got the following result

```
root@pdu:/usr/share/snmp/mibs# smilint -l 6 -i namelength-32 ./RFC1213-MIB.txt
./RFC1213-MIB.txt:15: warning: redefinition of identifier `SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2'
/usr/share/mibs/ietf/SNMPv2-SMI:13: info: previous definition of `mib-2'
./RFC1213-MIB.txt:19: warning: redefinition of identifier `SNMPv2-TC::DisplayString'
/usr/share/mibs/ietf/SNMPv2-TC:53: info: previous definition of `DisplayString'
./RFC1213-MIB.txt:28: warning: redefinition of identifier `SNMPv2-TC::PhysAddress'
/usr/share/mibs/ietf/SNMPv2-TC:87: info: previous definition of `PhysAddress'
./RFC1213-MIB.txt:56: warning: redefinition of identifier `SNMPv2-SMI::transmission'
/usr/share/mibs/ietf/SNMPv2-SMI:14: info: previous definition of `transmission'
./RFC1213-MIB.txt:268: index element `ifIndex' of row `ifEntry' must have a range restriction
./RFC1213-MIB.txt:616: index element `atIfIndex' of row `atEntry' must have a range restriction
./RFC1213-MIB.txt:1308: index element `ipNetToMediaIfIndex' of row `ipNetToMediaEntry' must have a range restriction
./RFC1213-MIB.txt:19: warning: type `DisplayString' has no format specification
./RFC1213-MIB.txt:28: warning: type `PhysAddress' has no format specification
```

[image]

Then after restarting the SNMP daemon I observed it not reflecting in the MIB browser as shown in the below image,
[image]

What will be the reason for not reflecting the variable in the MIB browser?
Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: To extend NET-SNMP based agents, you can follow old discussions or its documentation, https://net-snmp.sourceforge.io/wiki/index.php/Tut:Extending_snmpd_using_shell_scripts Keep in mind you are not supposed to edit/extend any SNMP standard MIB documents. They are parts of the standards and should remain still.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. so, If I want to make one new MIB file in that case do I need to write a script file? @Lex Li

Comment: I'm not sure about the "write a script" part - the MIB file is one thing but there has to be some logic that gets the data from your system to display or send to an snmp client. Regarding the "do not extend any standard MIB" comment above: under this link - https://pen.iana.org/pen/PenApplication.page - you could apply for your own "enterprise" OID below "1.3.6.1.4.1". There is also an OID for "documentation" purposes - see: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5612

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever `MIB` files we will make the same we need to add them to the `MIB browser` by using the `load mib browser` option normally we can find the same in the `file` option from the menu bar.

After adding the same we can use all the `SNMP` commands from any device which consists of the MIB Browser.